# Access files from BTRFS image on similar filesystem

Tags: mount, btrfs, raspbian

Backgroud: Running XBian (Debian ARM distribution for Raspberry Pi), which uses BTRFS. I fragged my system and decided to start over. However, I ripped the image from the root filesystem device before starting fresh.

I have a running BTRFS system, and an image (raw filesystem data) file which contains the data from a previous installation. I want to access the data from this image file to restore configuration and things like that. So, I mount this image with the following command (I found the offset with `fdisk /path/to/image.img`, print, and then multiplied the start sector by 512, the sector size - e.g. start sector 10000, offset = 512*10000 = 5120000):

```
mount -t btrfs -o loop,offset=5120000 /path/to/image.img /mnt/prev-image
```

After this command, I see that (at `/mnt/prev-image/`) the filesystem doesn't look as straightforward as ext2 or other traditional filesystems. I am probably having a misunderstanding at this point, or with the `mount` command.

When I try to access a file from the image, say my Samba configuration, I navigate to `/mnt/prev-image/root/@/etc/samba/smb.conf`. But, I notice that I'm seeing the same filesystem as my main filesystem and that the `smb.conf` file I access is the same as my current Samba configuration in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. I think BTRFS is treating the data in the image file as a baseline snapshot for my base system, and serving me the "latest" `smb.conf` file, which comes from my fresh installation.

I want to know how to access the data from the image file, and where my misunderstandings lie.

Answer (score 2):

Your probable problem is that you've mounted the wrong subvolume.  To mount the "parent" subvolume, throw an additional parameter into your "-o" section:
subvolid=1
such that your whole line would now look like

```
mount -t btrfs -o loop,offset=5120000,subvolid=1 /path/to/image.img /mnt/prev-image
```

I *think* that should do the trick for you.

Comment: Mounting like this still merges the filesystems so that I can't see the two separate files. This works well when mounting on a non-btrfs system, though.